# Windows DNS resolution

Tags: windows, dns, resolution

I can't connect to a server in my domain

```
C:\Users\evil>nslookup winserver
Server:  m0n0wall.local
Address:  192.168.123.254

Name:    winserver
Address:  192.168.123.246
```

this is ok, nslookup finds the server

however

```
C:\Users\evil>ping winserver
Ping request could not find host winserver. Please check the name and try again.
```

This is rather weird, any hints?

Answer (score 2):

See my comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/91067/dns-responding-only-to-nslookup-in-windows-7/105737#105737). NSLOOKUP queries the DNS server directly, whereas ping uses name resolution as provided by the operating system.